# Will an externally damaged passport pose a problem when applying for UK visa?

Tags: visas, passports, indian-citizens

I removed stickers of my [IELTS exam](https://www.ielts.org/) from my passport, and that left some white colour on my passport back page.

Will this cause me any problems when applying for a UK visa?

Comment: As long as all the pages are not tampered with, any residue (like white glue, etc.) on the cover of the passport is of no concern.

Comment: You can always use a little rubbing alcohol to remove any adhesive residue from your passport's back cover.

Comment: @Tom I tried that with my US passport, and it removed some of the finish from the cover, too, so there is a spot that is less shiny and slightly lighter in color.

Answer (score 7):

No, that should not cause any problem - the minor damage you describe doesn't meet the criteria for a 'damaged passport', which are:

> A damaged passport is one which isn’t in a condition to be accepted as proof of identity.
>
> Damage may include the following:
>
> - details are indecipherable
> - the laminate has lifted enough to allow the possibility of photo substitution
> - discolouration to the bio-data page
> - chemical or ink spillage on any page
> - missing or detached pages
> - the chip or antenna shows through the end paper on the back cover for the new style e-passports
> - the chip has been identified as damaged after investigation

[Damaged and faulty passports: guidance for examiners - UK Government, 10 November 2016](https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/damaged-and-faulty-passports/damaged-and-faulty-passports-policy)